# Get data from jquery dialog when close the dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Try to get data from jquery dialog box. I got it at first time. but next time data is same
this is my code

```
window.$('<div align="center" style="width:100%;height:100%;"><iframe id="ictdg" src="item_new_cat.php?itty='+itty+'" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>')
            .dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 400, 
                height: 250,
                title: 'New Category Registration',
                buttons: [{
                    text: "Save and Close",
                    click: function(){
                        var nwcg=$('#ictdg').contents().find('#nwct').val();
                        alert(nwcg); // This Data Not Refress ???
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }]
            });
```

Comment: Could make JSFiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the functionality in your button click to an outside function, instead of:

```
buttons: [{
    text: "Save and Close",
    click: function(){
        var nwcg=$('#ictdg').contents().find('#nwct').val();
        alert(nwcg); // This Data Not Refress ???
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
}]
```

try:

```
function getValue(){
    var nwcg=$('#ictdg').contents().find('#nwct').val();
    alert(nwcg); // This Data Not Refress ???
    $(this).dialog("close");
}
```

and

```
buttons: [{
    text: "Save and Close",
    click: getValue
}]
```

I think what happens is when you initialise the dialog with the inline function it runs once and always retruns the same value.

Comment: Same Problem, Value not refereeing, First time get value repeated when every closing.